# Trello Label Id in microsoft Flow

Tags: sharepoint, trello, power-automate

i am trying to create a flow using  Microsoft flow.The flow creates a card in Trello when an item is created in SharePoint list.I need to add a label to each card.The Flow gives me an option to specify the Label Id.How can i get the id of labels in Trello?I tried with #1 and also the color of the label.But dint work.If anyone knows the answer, please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question! This is actually really simple. Go to any board and add `.json` at the end of the url. Search for `idLabels` or `labels`. If the cards on the board have any labels the info should be right there.

Happy trelloing!

Answer (score 1):

Just a kind suggestion to help any others that stumble on this. A more efficient way of doing this would be to open a card that has the label for which you are interested. Then add ".json" to the end of that URL. The label id is them much easier to find and associate. If you want all the label id's then you can add all the relevant labels to a single card and follow the sample process. Then you have all the label id's in on single chunck in the json code.